# Populate Spring Bean with the return value of a function

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I want to populate a value of my spring bean with the return value of a method. Is there any way I can do this?

```
<bean id="JmsTemplate" class="org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate">
    <property name="defaultDestinationName"
            value="#Value#returned#by#method" />
```

I already have a bean of the class which has the method in my application context.

```
 <bean id=xyz class=path.to.xyz>    
</bean>
```

Please note that the value that I want to inject is not a variable, but return value of a method.

Comment: I have edited my answer to show how a method can be called. check it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`factory-bean` and `factory-method`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/beans.html#beans-factory-class-instance-factory-method):

```
<bean id="JmsTemplate" class="org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate">
  <property name="defaultDestinationName">
    <bean factory-bean="xyz" factory-method="methodName" />
  </property>
</bean>
```

If the method you want to call takes parameters you can pass them in using `constructor-arg`

```
<bean factory-bean="xyz" factory-method="methodName">
  <constructor-arg index="0" value="firstParameter" />
  <constructor-arg index="1" ref="someOtherBean" />
</bean>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can just do

```
<bean id="JmsTemplate" class="org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate">
    <property name="defaultDestinationName"
            value="#{className.methodName()}" />
```

The spring container will call the geter method for that property

**Note:** you woudl have to autowire `path.to.xyzConfig` using `@autowire`

References [1](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/expressions.html) : Look for this : `6.4 Expression support for defining bean definitions`

Comment: Updated my question . Sorry for not explaining my use case properly earlier . Can you let me know how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved with Spring expression language

```
<bean id="b1" class="B1">
</bean>

<bean id="b2" class="B2">
    <property name=xxx" value="#{b1.xxx}" />
</bean>
```

Comment: Updated my question . Sorry for not explaining my use case properly earlier . Can you let me know how to do this.

Comment: my example will work like this b2.setXxx(b1.getXxx())

Answer (score 0):

[This question could help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14072314/inject-the-value-of-an-enum-into-a-property-using-spring)

In short, you could use a factory method to return the value you want.